# Straightforward custom validation in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I've created this validation function:

```
private customValidateField(c: FormControl): any {
    return c.value[0] === 'a' ? null : { notValid: true };
}
```

So, on my reactive form:

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder)
{
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    field: ['', Validators.required, this.customValidateField],
    ...
  }
}
```

When I'm writing any character into this field I'm getting this error:

> Error: Expected validator to return Promise or Observable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just used `Validators.compose`:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  field: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, this.validateCardNumber])],
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 11):

The third item in the "field" array is an asynchronous validator (or an array of them). So to specify multiple synchronous validators, you need to:

Pass them as an array

```
this.fb.group({
  'formControlName': [this.hero.name, [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(4)
  ]]
});
```

or combine them (as Jordi wrote) using

```
Validators.compose(...)
```

FormBuilder API doc doesn't discuss the parameters in detail, but since it's just a shortcut for creating FormGroup with FormControl-s, you can take a look at the FormControl constructor:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControl-class.html